# How to Combine Columns from 2 Sources and Bind to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have:
1 Datatable - EmployeeAccess &
1 View - View_HCM

Both have the same column (EmpNo), View_HCM have 1000+ data where EmployeeAccess have only 4 data.
View_HCM has email address field and EmployeeAccess has none. I need to get email address from View_HCM according to the 4 data.

```
public List<EmployeeAccess> EmployeeAccess2()
{
    EmployeeAccess EA = new EmployeeAccess();
    View_HCM VH = new View_HCM();

    var x = from b in contxt.View_HCM
            where b.EmpNo == EA.EmpNo
            select b.EmailAddress;

    return x.ToList();
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Systems.Generic.Collections.String<string>' to ... '< list >'
```

Comment: x is of type IEnumerable<string>  and you want to return List<EmployeeAccess>

Comment: Change List<EmployeeAccess> to List<string> if you just want to get the email adresses.

Comment: @user3386000, the error is simply self explanatory.

Comment: Thank you. Now how to get email address corresponding to the data?
I already have #Eval ("Email Address") also #Eval ("EmpNo") but GridView doesn't show any data at all.

GridView already working, showing EmpNo with my previous code.

Comment: @ChristianMark the error is not my main problem.

Comment: How do you bind data to your gridview?

Comment: gridEmployeeAccess.DataSource = TAClass.EmployeeAccess2();
gridEmployeeAccess.DataBind();

Comment: And how you build your gridview in aspx, how you define the columns? You have a problem bounding your fields, this should be another question

Comment: All functional, displaying data from my previous code. I don't know how to inner join with linq.
,When I debug, I get no data, "Count = 0".

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212868/retrieve-a-column-from-view-to-datatable/22212909?noredirect=1#22212909

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return type is wrong.

To fix the errror change the returned type:

```
public List<string> EmployeeAccess2()
{
EmployeeAccess EA = new EmployeeAccess();
View_HCM VH = new View_HCM();

var x = from b in contxt.View_HCM
        where b.EmpNo == EA.EmpNo
        select b.EmailAddress;

return x.ToList();
}
```

And to show the email address in the gridview you can do like this

Define a class with a single named field:

```
public class EmailRecord
{
public string EmailAddress{ get; set; }
}


public List<EmailRecord> EmployeeAccess2()
{
EmployeeAccess EA = new EmployeeAccess();
View_HCM VH = new View_HCM();

var x = from b in contxt.View_HCM
        where b.EmpNo == EA.EmpNo
        select new EmailRecord
{
    EmailAddress = b.EmailAddress
};

return x.ToList();
}
```

Bind your grid

```
gridEmployeeAccess.DataSource = TAClass.EmployeeAccess2(); gridEmployeeAccess.DataBind();
```

In aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridEmployeeAccess" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailAddress" headertext="Email Address"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great new idea. This will come in handy for future reference as it gives me new concepts.

I've been trying to implement your code for a few hours but the only problem left is when I start debugging at "DataSource", it shows "=0".

Anyway thanks for the resolve.

Comment: * "EA.EmpNo" is null while debugging.

Comment: Great that helped you. I don't know what are those EmployeeAccess and View_HCM. You can use linq only on collections. Have a look at EnityFramework.

Comment: Oh okay I get it. They're dbml and edmx objects, from my database in SQL Server 2005. View_HCM is a query result, and EmployeeAccess is a table.